# How to remove null values in lat long in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using this below query and it is giving me an error.  The error that I am getting is at the very bottom.  The error is caused by lat and long having null values in a few of my transactions.  I have put the code in to remove all null from lat and long in each of the 3 tables.

What can I do to get the query working.  Query works fine and outputs about 100 rows, till the point that it comes across the first null values and then throws up the error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.region,
    c.Market_zone,
    c.delivery_center_zone,
    a.period,
    a.E3Location_num,
    a.dad_name,
    a.dad_latitude, 
    a.dad_longitude,
    c.lat,
    c.long,
    z.latitude,
    z.longitude,
    a.event_date,
    a.units,
    a.driver_num,
    d.driver_name,
    a.delivery_reason,
    b.description,
    c.wsensor,
    a.autowillstatus,
    a.delivery_exception,
    a.phone_order,
    a.cancel,
    c.lob,
    a.zone,
    a.keyindex,
    f.exception_reasons,
    ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-a.dad_latitude)) *COS(RADIANS(90-c.lat)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-a.dad_latitude)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-c.lat)) *COS(RADIANS(a.dad_longitude-c.long))) *6371 as kms_from_tank,
    CASE 
        WHEN ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-a.dad_latitude)) *COS(RADIANS(90-c.lat)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-a.dad_latitude)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-c.lat)) *COS(RADIANS(a.dad_longitude-c.long))) *6371 > 5 then 'N'
        ELSE 'Y'
    END as Cancelled_on_Tanksite,
    ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-a.dad_latitude)) *COS(RADIANS(90-z.latitude)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-a.dad_latitude)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-z.latitude)) *COS(RADIANS(a.dad_longitude-z.longitude))) *6371 as kms_from_yard,
    CASE 
        WHEN ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-a.dad_latitude)) *COS(RADIANS(90-z.latitude)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-a.dad_latitude)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-z.latitude)) *COS(RADIANS(a.dad_longitude-z.longitude))) *6371 > 5 then 'N'
        ELSE 'Y'
    END as Cancelled_at_Yard,
    a.E3Location_num + '-' + CAST(a.event_date AS varchar (50)) AS unique_id,
    a.size,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.size = '2222' THEN 'MMT'
        WHEN a.size = '22222' THEN 'MMT'
        WHEN a.size = '0' THEN 'Cyl'
        ELSE 'BULK'
    END AS Department 
FROM
    e3.dbo.E3table_1 (nolock)a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM openquery(suppro_supw, 'SELECT reason_id, description
                                           FROM DELIVERY_REASON
                                           AT isolation 0')) b ON a.delivery_reason = b.reason_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM [SPPWEBPDNJ04].[Delivery_Customer_Master].[dbo].[Del_Customer_Master] 
     WHERE lat IS NOT NULL AND long IS NOT NULL) c ON c.Location = a.E3Location_num 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM openquery(suppro_supw, 'SELECT driver_id, driver_name
                                           FROM DRIVER_HEADER 
                                           AT isolation 0')) d ON d.driver_id = a.driver_num
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM openquery(SUPPRO_SUPW, 'SELECT
cc.full_account
,ee.tank_num 
,aa.name
,ee.driver_num
,aa.delivery_hold
,aa.department_code
,dd.size
,bb.exception_reasons
,dd.delivery_type
,ee.event_date

FROM
ACCOUNTS aa,
DELIVERY_EXCEPTION bb,
FULL_ACCOUNT cc,
TRANS_DELIVERY dd,
TRANS_MAIN ee

WHERE
aa.account_num = bb.account_num
AND aa.account_num = cc.account_num
AND aa.account_num = dd.account_num
AND aa.account_num = ee.account_num
AND bb.account_num = cc.account_num
AND bb.account_num = dd.account_num
AND bb.trx_unique_key = dd.trx_unique_key
AND bb.trx_unique_key = ee.trx_unique_key
AND cc.account_num = dd.account_num
AND ee.event_date > "2020-01-01" 
and bb.exception_reasons like ''%SECOND%'' 

AT ISOLATION 0'))f
on rtrim(f.full_account)+'-'+cast(f.tank_num as varchar (3)) = a.E3Location_num
and f.event_date = a.event_date

left join
(Select * FROM e3.dbo.ADDs_Delivery_centers_info (nolock) where latitude is not null and longitude is not null) z
on z.Delivery_center_num = a.cost_center

where 
a.driver_num > 0
and truck_num > 0 
and a.units >= 0
and a.event_date > '2019-01-01'
and a.Posting_code in (1,2,10,99)
and a.region in ('AB1','BC1','PR1')
and a.dad_latitude is not null 
and a.dad_longitude is not null
```

I'm getting an error:

> Msg 3623, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> A domain error occurred

Comment: this error show that you have wrong parameter for one or more of the mathematics functions you are using , for example LOG(-1) or SQRT(-1) ,mathematically makes no sense and SQL returns that error message

Comment: an I assume you are using sql server 2005 , because error messgae text has changes in next sql server editions after 2005

Comment: yes using sql server 2005

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN allows nulls to come through when the JOIN statement fails to find a match on the right side of the table.

For example, when you

```sql
left join
(Select * FROM e3.dbo.ADDs_Delivery_centers_info (nolock) 
where latitude is not null and longitude is not null) z 
  on z.Delivery_center_num = a.cost_center
```

you will have a `null` z.latitude when there is no matching `z.Delivery_center_num`. Same with the other tables.

Either INNER JOIN those tables to guarantee values every time, or handle null possibilities inside every single math operation.

EDIT:

After reviewing the BOL (since my trig is dismal), it looks as if [ACOS will throw that exact error if the value is outside the range of -1 to 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/acos-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016). We need to put error handling within the ACOS statements, but it will look horrific within your query, so I recommend you create a UDF to handle it for you cleanly.

For example,

```sql
-- Test: 
-- if this statement generates an error, replace the NULL in the function 
-- with 1. I don't have an old enough server to confirm whether it could handle NULL. 
select ACOS(null) 
go


create function myACOS (@inp float)
returns float 
as begin 
declare @ret float 
    
    select @ret = 
        acos(   /* check whether our input exceeds the boundaries of ACOS; if it does, replace it with something harmless */
                case when @inp < -1 or @inp > 1 then null 
                else @inp end)
    
return @ret
end
```

Then, you update your SELECT statement to use this function instead of the built in ACOS everywhere, so it does your error handling behind the scenes:

```sql
SELECT 
   dbo.myACOS(COS(blah blah blah...)) *6371 as kms_from_tank
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed all the joins to Inner join however problem persists, sorry can you give me an example of how  "handle null possibilities inside every single math operation.", do you mean in each bracket of Acos(cos(Radians..) I ought to handle null values?  it would help if you can somehow give me an example of how to write that?

Comment: I reviewed the books online (which, technically, *you* should have also checked before posting), and it looks as if ACOS is the only function in your query that would give that error. I updated my answer to reflect how to handle that cleanly. In the future, though, to handle null values is literally ISNULL(myCol, 1) or whatever your want your replacement value to be. So, ```COS(RADIANS(90-ISNULL(a.dad_latitude, 0)))``` is how you could handle NULL values, if those were what were giving you the error. (They weren't.)